# will an old wheelset support 28mm (28c) 700c tires or will they "balloon"

Tags: tire

My bike is early 2000s and came with Shimano wh-r540 wheelset and 26mm tires

googling shows ETRTO: 622 x 13C (internal width?) and 19mm (external width?)

I've successfully used 25mm tires but considering going to 28mm since I believe there is clearance everywhere important for a tire that wide

However I am questioning if the rim is too narrow to properly support a 28mm and that it will "balloon" defeating the benefits of 28mm

But I've noticed new bikes that come with 28mm typically have a very wide rim to support the tire so the tire sits more square or inwards and not ballon out

ie. modern rim + 28mm tire profile =   /----\

ie. old 540 rim + 28mm tire profile =   \----/

does it matter? will it defeat the benefits of 28mm for handling?

Comment: I do not know what the 'x 13C' part of the spec means, but the 19mm spec is the *internal* rim width (which is the relevant width for tires, because they fit inside the rim). The Shimano datasheet can be found here: http://bike.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Wheel/ROAD/WH-7701-R540/SI-4AM0E-Po_v1_m56577569830607451.pdf

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus That's incorrect, the 18.8mm largura do aro (rim width) measurement on that link is referring to the outside dimension. 13mm is the inside. People like sticking the C on there because of confusion about what it actually indicates.

Comment: I mean to paste in a link the sheet in english: http://fish.shimano-eu.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Wheel/ROAD/WH-7701-R540/SI-4AM0E-En_v1_m56577569830611927.pdf

Comment: The difference between 26mm and 28mm tires is inconsequential, unless the existing tire is already on the hairy edge of fitting the rim.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus thank you for that PDF, it actually shows Shimano themselves say the acceptable tire range for the WH-R540 is `700C (19-28C)` at the bottom, so I assume 28mm is indeed the maximum acceptable

Answer (score 3):

Wider road rims have become more popular, in part because of the reasons you're talking about, but 28 is far from the reasonable maximum for a more classic 19-20mm road rim, and will be totally fine. Consider how many people race cross on 19-20mm clinchers with 32s and 35s. Where the actual line is of what's reasonable is a hotly debated topic that there are other questions about.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ArgentiApparatus posting the technical paper from Shimano about the WH-R540 which clearly states that 28C is the maximum recommended width for best performance

[image]